# Does QuickBooks provide API to connect with Google Calender?

Tags: laravel, google-calendar-api, quickbooks

I wanted to integrate QuickBooks with Google Calendar into my project, but could not find any direct API from QuickBooks. I'm only getting third party options to do that.

Is there any possibility to do it directly with the Intuit API.

Comment: Well, you can [INTEGRATE GOOGLE CALENDAR WITH QUICKBOOKS](https://www.pipethru.com/enterprise/GoogleCalendar/QuickbooksOnline) but through API, there is no option here in [calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/) that can manage that integration. So like you said, I think only 3rd party products can help you with it.